# Continuity of Given Function of $f: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Consider, $f: \mathbb{Q} \to \mathbb{Q}$,
$$
\begin{align}
f(x) = \begin{cases}
0 & \text{if $x=0$}\\
\frac{1}{m} & \text{if $x = \frac{n}{m}$ where $n \in \mathbb{Z},m \in \mathbb{N},\gcd(m,n) = 1$}
\end{cases}
\end{align}
$$

Now, I did a sketch of this in the unit interval to get a feeling of what this function is doing, and it seems to be generating this triangle like graph.  Intuition tells me this function is not continuous by the graph, but this is not a mathematical proof, which is what I need.

While attempting an $\epsilon-\delta$ proof,I considered the fact that $f(1/2)=1/2 , f(1000/2001)=1/2001$, thus $\vert \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{2001}\vert$ is very small and thus this can be generalized, but am unsure as to how this construction would be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following proof is a bit terse. You can fill in any small details.

We have continuity at $x=0$. Indeed, for any $\epsilon>0$ choose $n$ such that $0<\frac 1n < \epsilon$ and let $\delta = \frac{1}{n}$. Then each $x \in \mathbb{Q} \cap (-\delta, \delta)$ has a denominator larger than $n$, hence $f[\mathbb{Q} \cap (-\delta, \delta)] \subset [-\frac 1n, \frac 1n] \subset (-\epsilon, \epsilon)$.

However, we have continuity nowhere else. $f$ maps any rational $x_0 \neq 0$  to a non-zero positive number. Hence, were $f$ continuous at $x_0 \neq 0$, there would be a $\delta>0$ such that $\inf\left(f[\mathbb{Q} \cap (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)]\right) > 0$. However, this is a contradiction since each neighbourhood of $x_0$ contains rationals with arbitrarily large denominators, which implies $\inf\left(f[\mathbb{Q} \cap (x_0 - \delta, x_0 + \delta)]\right) = 0$.

Comment: Notation Question: What is meant by "$f[\mathbb{Q} \cap (-\delta, \delta)]$"?

Comment: @ElSpiffy Well, $\cap$ is the intersection, so $\mathbb{Q} \cap (-\delta, \delta)$ is the set of rationals in the interval $(-\delta, \delta)$. $f[\mathbb{Q} \cap (-\delta, \delta)]$ is the image of this set under $f$.

Comment: Thank you for the thorough response; I have never seen this notation for the image of a function.

Comment: Sometimes normal parentheses are also used in place of brackets to denote image of a function ie $f(A) $ in place of $f[A]$ for some subset $A$ of domain of $f$.